# Solidity. Truffle test not passing "expected { _events: {},..." to equal

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

I can't get a test to pass, for me it is very clear but I am missing something obvious:

This is the smart contract:

```
function getContractOwner() public pure returns (string memory contractOwnerAddress) {
    return "0x67F4CfB03aA5E2E71De1470ae26adB7e33B7892E";
}
```

This is the test:

```
contract("Exams", async accounts => {
  it("should pass this test", async () => {
    assert.equal("0", "0", "LOGICAL!")
  });
  it("should keep the contract owner", async () => {

    let instance = await Exam.deployed();
    let address = instance.getContractOwner.call(accounts[0]);
    // console.log(address);
    assert.equal(address.valueOf(), "0x67F4CfB03aA5E2E71De1470ae26adB7e33B7892E", "the address is not correct");

  });
});
```

I get this error:

```
 Contract: Exams
    ✓ should pass this test
    1) should keep the contract owner
    > No events were emitted


  1 passing (74ms)   1 failing

  1) Contract: Exams
       should keep the contract owner:
     AssertionError: the address is not correct: expected { _events: {},   emit: [Function: emit],   on: [Function: on],   once: [Function: once],   off: [Function: removeListener],   listeners: [Function: listeners],   addListener: [Function: on],   removeListener: [Function: removeListener],   removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners] } to equal '0x67F4CfB03aA5E2E71De1470ae26adB7e33B7892E'
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/TestExams.js:15:15)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the invocation wrong, try with the following:

```
 it("should keep the contract owner", async () => {
   let instance = await Example.deployed();
   let address = await instance.getContractOwner.call({from: accounts[0]});
   // console.log(address);
   assert.equal(address.valueOf(), "0x67F4CfB03aA5E2E71De1470ae26adB7e33B7892E", "the address is not correct");
 });
```

Read about using `async/await` from the [Truffle docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript#using-async-await).

Tested:

```
$ truffle test
Using network 'development'.

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Example.sol
> Artifacts written to /tmp/test-1191021-9679-1hbjgq3.xdq8
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang

  Contract: Example
    ✓ should pass this test
    ✓ should keep the contract owner (45ms)

  2 passing (116ms)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know where can I find the documentation for this?

Comment: @AlejandroVeintimilla just updated my answer with that ;).